# Node http server response.write inside a function

Tags: node.js

```
  server = require('http').createServer(function(request, response){ 
        .. //writehead and stuff
        myfunction.Division.getByName(callback, function(params) {
              ... // [code being executed defining the response]
              myresponse = 'hello, world';
              response.write(myresponse); 
              ... // rest of the code
```

My question here is how to write the response when my code has been executed ?

`server.on(something)` perhaps ? Not sure.

**EDIT:** 
<strike>Someone once said if it's stupid but it works it is not stupid.</strike>

The mess up was due the async call of this object. Nevertheless I am calling this entire object from external file. using `fs`

```
   case 'current':  
       eval ( fs.readFileSync (__dirname+'/data/current/current.js') );
       console.log(BB); 
   break;
```

I was trying to write my response in this file where my function was, but that's wrong since it never waited for that fail to execute. When I defined before `myfunction.Division.getByName` a variable called `BB` which is supposed to be my response (it could go even higher in my code) and modified it inside `myfunction.Division.getByName` the call after `fs` function executed perfectly. 
So I can get the `response.write` after the `fs` call.

So far it's working fine, numerous attempts with timeouts and such, but the sync call from fs is fixing it perfectly. If there are bugs I will look for solution and update again.

Comment: After which code has been executed?

Comment: my bad, updated the sample

Comment: Looks to me like that's exactly what you are doing, what's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that it won't work it can't call the response inside the object `myfunction`

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the callback from `.getByName()` is not being called at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*can't call the response inside the object `myfunction`*"? Do you mean `response` is undefined or it throws or it just doesn't do something? Remember until you call `end` on the response, nothing will be sent to the client.

Comment: nothing happens, there is an end after the getByName is completed I just can't access it inside and this function is above my level to comprehend what's the callback, where it's rotating around the files it uses stuff like promises, module exports that I am not familiar with and as far as I am concerned I need only to call this response inside to get it done

Comment: @JustDeveloper your going to have to expand the example to show a short but complete version of your code.